# Identify Category of Cell Based on Cell Being Underneath Category

Tags: google-sheets

Thank you in advance for assisting.  I'm looking at the following sheet and I need to identify with a formula the category (e.g. Employer & College) when looking at items below it.  In other words, Nationwide and Geico belong to Employer because they're below it.  College starts another category and thus University of Alabama and UCLA - MBA belong to it. A category is defined by having a "." at the end of it.

```
Date
Name
Title
Employer.
Nationwide
Geico
College.
University of Alabama
UCLA - MBA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the **formula**:

`=QUERY(filter({VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A),QUERY({ROW(A:A),if(RIGHT(A:A)=".",A:A,"")},"select * where Col2 <> ''"),2),if(RIGHT(A:A)<>".",A:A,"")},A:A<>""),"select * where Col2 <>''")`

**Input** in column A:

```
Employer.
Nationwide
Geico
College.
University of Alabama
UCLA - MBA
```

The **result**:

```
Employer.   Nationwide
Employer.   Geico
College.    University of Alabama
College.    UCLA - MBA
```